# How To Download A Image (Canvas) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to this download concept in JavaScript. In my application I create a QR code (Canvas Image). By using JavaScript then, I want to download the QR code on click of a button. How can I proceed with this?

I also did it in PHP as shown below

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
readfile($file);
```

It works easily but how can I accomplish the same in JavaScript

Also I want to rotate the image on click of a button.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Canvas2Image](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/) library.

> This is a small library that lets you easily save a HTML5 canvas element as an imagefile.

Answer (score 1):

### You can download any image with this method. I'm using click() function here.

If your body element have not already an anchor element [<a></a>] :

```
function download(dataURL){
  let elmnt = document.querySelectorAll('a') || 
  document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  let length = elmnt.length;
  document.body.innerHTML+=`<a href=${x} download>Download</a>`;
  elmnt[length+1].click();
}
```

or (RECOMENDED) :

```
function download(dataURL) {
    let elmnt = document.createElement("a");
    elmnt.href=dataURL;
    elmnt.setAttribute("download", "download");
    elmnt.click();
}
```

If your body element have already an anchor element [<a></a>] :

```
function download(dataURL,elmnt) {
    if (elmnt===undefined) elmnt=document.querySelector('a') || document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    elmnt.href=dataURL;
    elmnt.setAttribute("download","download");
    elmnt.click();
}
```

### A full example with a canvas element:

If your body element have not already an anchor element [<a></a>] :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <img id="scream" width="220" height="277" src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_the_scream.jpg" alt="The Scream">

    <p>Canvas:</p>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="240" height="297" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>

    <script>

        window.onload = function () {
            var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
            var img = document.getElementById("scream");
            ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
        }

        function download(dataURL){
            let elmnt = document.querySelectorAll('a') || 
            document.getElementsByTagName('a');
            let length = elmnt.length;
            document.body.innerHTML+=`<a href=${x} download>Download</a>`;
            elmnt[length+1].click();
        }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

or (RECOMMENDED) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <img id="scream" width="220" height="277" src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_the_scream.jpg" alt="The Scream">

    <p>Canvas:</p>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="240" height="297" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>

    <script>

        window.onload = function () {
            var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
            var img = document.getElementById("scream");
            ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
        }

        function download(dataURL, elmnt) {
            if (elmnt === undefined) elmnt = document.querySelector('a') || document.getElementsByTagName('a');
            elmnt.href = dataURL;
            elmnt.setAttribute("download", "download");
            elmnt.click();
        }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

If your body element have already an anchor element [<a></a>] :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <img id="scream" width="220" height="277" src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_the_scream.jpg" alt="The Scream">

    <p>Canvas:</p>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="240" height="297" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>

    <script>

        window.onload = function () {
            var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
            var img = document.getElementById("scream");
            ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
        }

        function download(dataURL,elmnt) {
            if (elmnt===undefined) elmnt=document.querySelector('a') || document.getElementsByTagName('a');
            elmnt.href=dataURL;
            elmnt.setAttribute("download","download");
            elmnt.click();
        }

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```